# Is it possible to show a recycleview with viewpager

Tags: android

Before i start i am thinking is it possible to show a layout with some textviews and a recycleview ... with viewpager ?? 
something like a layout like below and and i want to show it with viewpager . is it possible ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/dynamic"
>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20px"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
    android:text="New Text" />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

ok... i tried it on my exsisting porject and it crushed and i dont know why ...
sample code below
class from where i call viewpager adapter:

```
public class Details_page extends AppCompatActivity {
ViewPager viewPager;
CustomSwipAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_page);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar= getSupportActionBar();
    if(actionBar!=null)
    {
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] array=bundle.getStringArray("s");
    int point=Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
    String title_head=array[2];
    setTitle(title_head);
    String catagory=array[1];
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor=getdata(getApplicationContext(),catagory);



    viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter =new CustomSwipAdapter(this,cursor,point);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(point);
}
public Cursor getdata(Context context,String catagory)
{
    Db_helper db_helper;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    Cursor cursor;
    db_helper = new Db_helper(context);
    sqLiteDatabase = db_helper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db_helper.getallInformations(sqLiteDatabase, catagory);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    db_helper.close();

    return cursor;
}

}
```

viewpager adapter

```
public class CustomSwipAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Cursor cursor;
private int point;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private IELTS_detail_row_adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
public CustomSwipAdapter(Context context,Cursor cursor,int point)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.cursor=cursor;
    this.point=point;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cursor.getCount();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view==(LinearLayout)object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    List<Mentor_detail_row_info> data=new ArrayList<>();
    layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swip_layout,container,false);
    TextView textView=(TextView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.page_title);
    TextView textView1=(TextView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
    recyclerView =(RecyclerView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_detail);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(context, null, false, true));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


    textView1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    textView.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    textView1.setText(cursor.getString(3));
    String[]links=cursor.getString(3).split(";");
    for(int i=0;i<=links.length;i++)
    {
        Mentor_detail_row_info current=new Mentor_detail_row_info();
        if(links[i]!=null)
        {
            current.link=links[i];
            data.add(current);
        }
    }
    adapter=new IELTS_detail_row_adapter(context,data);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    container.addView(item_view);


    return item_view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
   container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
}
}
```

and recycleview adapter

```
public class IELTS_detail_row_adapter extends     RecyclerView.Adapter<IELTS_detail_row_adapter.Mentor_menu_viewHolder> {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Mentor_detail_row_info> data = Collections.emptyList();
Context context;
private ClickListener clickListener;

public IELTS_detail_row_adapter(Context context, List<Mentor_detail_row_info> data) {
    this.context=context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;

}

@Override
public Mentor_menu_viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_detail, parent, false);
    Mentor_menu_viewHolder holder = new Mentor_menu_viewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Mentor_menu_viewHolder holder, int position) {
    Mentor_detail_row_info current = data.get(position);
    holder.link.setText(current.link);

}
public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener)
{
    this.clickListener=clickListener;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class Mentor_menu_viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView link;

    public Mentor_menu_viewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        link = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_list_link);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Mentor_detail_row_info current=data.get(getAdapterPosition());
        clickListener.ItemClick(v,current.link);

    }

}
public interface ClickListener{
    public void ItemClick(View view,String link);

}

}
```

Comment: why wouldn't it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

You can setup your recyclerview in the fragment you call as pages of the ViewPager. While the ViewPager load your fragments the recyclerviews are instantiate and populate.

Cons: you could experience lag between horizontal swipes (viewpager), and vertical swipes (recyclerview).

If you need an answer more specific, please ask a more specific question.

Comment: i just tried it on my existing project and it crushed ..:p can u pls check it out where i made mistake . i upload the code ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FragmentPagerAdapter` to your viewPager and add recyclerView to your fragment. Use this source as example - https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare